# Does azure function support ipv6?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, ipv6

Try to write a small azure function to init a tcp connection to a ipv6 address. Always get failure. Error message shows "An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions" Does azure function support ipv6 at all?

Comment: All of the App Service don't support ipv6. The only way you can do is create a front door and use it as the entrance of your azure function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not only azure function. All of the App Service doesn't support ipv6. This is by design. But you can use Azure Front door to acheive your goal.

Azure Front Door natively supports end-to-end IPv6 connectivity and also HTTP/2 protocol.

For example, I have a app service. It doesn't support ipv6.

[image]

So, I create a front door of this app service.(Use front door as the entrance.)

Go to 'All Service' on portal -> search 'Front door' -> create front door, and add your web app as the backend host in this page.

And at last, you can use front door to access your web app, it support ipv6.(Azure Function is designed based on Web App Sandbox, so it is the same.)

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That helps! I think that can solve the issue if client require a Ipv6 to talk to. In my case, I want the web app to talk to a ipv6 address, will it work?

Answer (score 0):

> Does azure function support ipv6 at all?

There is **not currently IPv6 support for Azure Functions** as of yet.

For more details, you could refer to this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/4992369-support-ipv6-throughout-the-azure-platform).